# How to handle inaccurate comments

Tags: discussion, comments

In [this question thread](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/225209/what-does-cracked-the-door-a-sliver-mean) a user has declared that "sliver" is "not a word". This is simply incorrect, as a simple dictionary lookup will show. Is ther any prefered way to handle such provably inaccurate comments?

Answer (score 4):

In this particular case, it's worth noting that the author of the original comment deleted that comment after reading your response and your improved answer.

This is actually a healthy way to handle the situation. Your comment refuted the original comment, but your remarks were more respectful than argumentative; they were intended to clear up a simple misunderstanding rather than insult the person who was ultimately incorrect. Consequently, that person learned something new and the Code of Conduct was never breached.

That's indeed the best way to handle it: make your point politely and respectfully. If that fixes the problem, great! If, on the other hand, things get heated, it's generally best to flag the comment and disengage.

Answer (score 2):

The comments have been cleaned up already because you handled it correctly-you updated your answer to address the concerns expressed in the comment.

Once you’ve updated your answer, flag the comments as “no longer needed” if your edit has made them no longer relevant.